# org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, rapidminer

I wanted to build rapidminer-studio-master, so I download the source code from github:https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-studio
According to the README.md file, I import the project into IDEA, then execute the command `gradlew jar`, but the error is:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateGitRevFile'.
> org.eclipse.jgit.errors.RepositoryNotFoundException: repository not found: 
E:\lyh\file\workspaces\rapidminerworkspace\rapidminer-studio-master
```

Then I open the file `props.gradle`,it shows that:
[image]

So the file has obviously added a corresponding dependency. Why is it still failing to load?

Answer (score 1):

actually it looks a bit strange that git is looking for a repo in your local file system.
Did you use `git clone` to download the repository? If not try this and see if it helps.

Best,
David

Comment: It seems like the gradle doesn't get the dependency needed, not the problem of source code. Because I got this error in the step of build while using 'gradlew jar'

Comment: Yes, because the build script is looking a git revision.
So if you clone the complete repository , the gradle wrapper should work as expected.

Comment: Mine too gives a local path. I was trying to be clever with parent repositories and I guess that's not a primary use case.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-x generateGitProperties` to your gradle command.